# Export a html table to a pdf with all its css intact

Tags: css, angularjs, pdf, html

I need to open a html table to a new tab as a pdf to be ready for printing.  Problem I am having is exporting the html table due to the css tied to it.  Many of the elements are colored differently depending on the row, cell, etc.  How can I export the table to a pdf with all the css intact?  I am using angularjs btw

In another part of the page, I had ui-grids created using angularjs and I was able to exporter them using pdf make.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, tough to know with complete certainty that this would work for you, but I have used fpdf to generate billing statements for customers. The output can be colored based on values of variables passed to it using the "SetTextColor" function. The call to fpdf is done usually as an ajax request on a button push, so you should be able to capture all the rows and columns of your table, and use the same type of logic to adjust the colors within your fpdf class.

For more information about fpdf: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Is it a basic html table using angular js.  I need all the data selected from a search filter to be exported to a pdf for printing.  As well as the css.  I believe i should find a solution using angular js